# Razor view works locally but not in Azure web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a weird problem. I have a page which has the following URL: `/ShowLead?leadid=3&customerid=9626` . When I enter this page locally and i run in Visual Studio **it works**, but when I enter it online I get the following **error**:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/ShowLead/Index.aspx
~/Views/ShowLead/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/ShowLead/Index.cshtml
~/Views/ShowLead/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web req
```

It is hosted as a completely standard Azure web app.

This is weird to me, because if we look at my folder structure, I DO have a Razor view at `~/Views/ShowLead/Index.cshtml`:

[image]

My controller looks like this:

```
public class ShowLeadController : Controller
{

    // GET: ShowLead
    public ActionResult Index(int leadid, int customerid)
    {
        // some amazing code that creates my viewmodel

        return View(vm);
    }   
 }
```

The view itself is:

```
@model Asano.Websites.LeadSender.Models.ViewModels.ShowLeadViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body style="padding-top: 20px; font-family: Helvetica">
    <div style="margin:25px;">
      // some of the best HTML the world has ever seen with inline styles
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I assume the problem is the `Layout = null`, but what I want to is that this view does NOT use a master, but works as a vanila page like this.

Comment: Are you sure this view is included in your project, because it will work locally but published folder does not contain your Index view.

Comment: Did you confirm the presence of the Showlead Folder and Index.cshtml file in your remote server? Also `Layout=null` is never a problem when it can't find the view.

Comment: You're both of course right. Build action was wrong... Leave an answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this view is included in your project, because it will work locally but published folder does not contain your Index view.